# Looking for special Highcharts chart

Tags: charts, data-visualization, highcharts

Im looking for a way to draw a chart where data is represent by one block per date. So if there is a data for this date a colored block appears, otherwise the place is left blank. The goal is to have a visualization of events over time. Where every colored block indicates the occurrence of a specific event.

Is there way to create such a chart using Highcharts and the Highstocks time slider.

Lets say I have event types `a`, `b` and `c`, the result should look like this.

```
|a| |a|       |a|
 - - - - - - - - 
|b|b|b|b|b|b|b|b|
 - - - - - - - - 
|c|   |c|
 -     -
```

Comment: A simple logarithmic chart which marker's symbol is square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a scatter chart, with custom shapes as markers.

Example how could this be done:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'scatter',
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1
    },
    series: [{
        data: [[0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1], [5,1]]        
    },{
        data: [[0,2],[2,2]]        
    },{
        data: [[1,3],[3,3]]        
    }]
});
```

And [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/54/)